# Как сделать поиск в таблице HTML по конктреным столбцам(одному или двум)

Tags: javascript

В данной таблице 4 столбца: ID, Название, Цена, Продажа.
Необходимо сделать поиск по двум первым столбцам(ID, Название). Помогите, пожалуйста =)

Использую данный код:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    search_table($(this).val());
  });

  function search_table(value) {
    $('#costs tr').each(function() {
      var found = 'false';
      $(this).each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
          found = 'true';
        }
      });
      if (found == 'true') {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Но почему же found строка? Не хватает ещё if (found.length === 4) :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пройдитесь по каждой строке (уже проходитесь), получите текст ячеек ID и Название, поищите в каждом из текстов, если хотя бы в одном найдено, то вы нашли :-)

UPD Как это сделать:

Внутри `$('#costs tr').each(function() {...}` `$(this)` -- это текущая строка. `$(this).find('td:lt(2)')` -- первые две ячейки текущей строки (лучше бы как-то отметить эти ячейки в вёрстке, а не полагаться на то что они идут первыми). `$(this).find('td:lt(2)').each` -- обход первых двух ячеек, `$(this).text()` внутри этого `each` -- текст текущей ячейки.

Остаётся только сделать `indexOf`, выставить `found`, и скрыть показать строку.

Comment: Ещё бы понять, как это сделать

Comment: @BraianKant обновил ответ. А вы код сами написали или скопировали откуда-нибудь? Понимаете как он работает?

Comment: Скопировал с англоязычного сайта. Частично понимаю, частично нет, плохо знаком с синтаксисом.

Comment: Читайте доку по jquery (https://api.jquery.com). И вот посмотрите пример (для изучения, не копирования в код вашего проекта) https://jsfiddle.net/1ymbkcez/ фильтруются строки по первым двум колонкам

Comment: Спасибо большое